# Cyrillic letters are incorrectly encoded in the C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing UTF8 encoded data from a Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671984/parsing-utf8-encoded-data-from-a-web-service)

I've written small web service which inserts data to the DB.

It takes parameter "comment":

```
CreateBuy(DateTime date, String cardNumber, Decimal amount, String comment) 
{
    ...
}
```

It works fine with latin letters, but when I try to pass value of comment = "Продукт1" it passes to the stored procedure value @comment = '?YN€????N???N‚1' instead of 'Продукт1'.

How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use localization parameters for this string. To avoid such problems, working both with english and russian better use Utf-8 encoding.