# Cyrillic letters GET request in REST web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, encoding, character-encoding

I have my REST web service that should receive GET encoded requests with cyrillic letters.

For example: www.service/srv?param1=%D1%E0%ED%EA%F2

I know that this is Windows-1251 ISO-8859-1, but as a value of input parameter in my web service function allways have something like question marks . I gues that service convert string to UTF-8.

Is it possible to recive GET request in Windows-1251 codepage?

There was a similar thread: [Cyrillic letters are incorrectly encoded in the C# Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562166/cyrillic-letters-are-incorrectly-encoded-in-the-c-sharp-web-service)
The answer was to use utf-8 encoding. But im my case I cant change request to web service.

Web service description:

```
[OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
            UriTemplate = @"param?p1={p1}&p2={p2}&p3={p3}…")]

   string MyFunction(string p1, string p2, string p3, …);
```

Comment: I just thought may be the solution is to prevent automatic decoding of GET parameters. If only function could get original encoded parameter, it is no big deal to decode it. Yet I don't know is it possible or not.

Comment: How do you read parameters from the URI's query string?

Comment: @SimonMourier Using WebInvoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution that I can come with is:

```
 PropertyInfo[] inf = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                HttpRequestMessageProperty val = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)inf[0].GetValue(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest, null);
                string paramString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(val.QueryString, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
                Uri address = new Uri("http://server.ru/services/service.svc/reg?" + paramString);

                p1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(address.Query).Get("p1");
                p2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(address.Query).Get("p2");
                p3 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(address.Query).Get("p3");
                ...
```

I'm wondered why globalization tag is not working in this case. 
Although this code works, I'm really appreciate any further suggestions on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your web.config like this:

```
<system.web> 
    <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" ... other stuff... /> 
</system.web>
```

Note it could have some other side effects on your app.

Comment: I tried it with Windows-1251, and right now tried as you suggest with iso-8859-1. But still no effect.