# Read non-ASCII chars from XML

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I've built a small program that reads the XML output from Google Maps API geocode service and parses the string using LINQ to XML.

If the XML returned contains non ASCII characters then my output seems to break. Is there a way to read/encode this differently?

Here is a snapshot of the key part of the code.

```
    public static void Read(IList<string> LocationDetails, string Type)
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                //Generate geocode request and read XML file to string
                string request = String.Format("Https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?{0}={1}&sensor=false", Type, LocationDetails[i]);
                string locationXML = webClient.DownloadString(request);
                XElement root = XElement.Parse(locationXML);

              //Check if request is OK or otherwise
              if (root.Element("status").Value != "OK")
              {     //Skip to next iteration if status not OK
                 continue;   
              }
            }
```

..... skip some declaration code. StateName declared as string.

```
    try
    {
        StateName = (result.Elements("address_component")
         .Where(x => (string)x.Element("type") == "administrative_area_level_1")
         .Select(x => x.Element("long_name").Value).First());
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        StateName = null;
    }
```

Comment: Where does your code "break"? Please provide some exception information or similar.

Comment: it's an encoding problem. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671984/parsing-utf8-encoded-data-from-a-web-service

Comment: @pdriegen: On the surface it looks like an encoding problem, but where is the bug? `WebClient.DownloadString` gets the character set from the HTTP header and should be able to properly decode the string. Internally strings in .NET are not encoded and `XElement.Parse` does not have to handle character sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the Google webservice will return XML encoded using UTF-8. However, if this information is absent from the HTTP header the `WebClient.DownloadString` method will use `Encoding.Default` to decode the returned bytes into a string. This is also called the "ANSI" encoding and in most cases is not UTF-8.

To fix this you need to perform the following assignment before calling `webclient.DownloadString(request)`:

```
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```